# Material become black when observe from angle

Tags: mesh, materials, subdivision-surface

If I observe mesh from acute angle it borders become black. I use PBR materials from Blender Guru.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem caused by the *fresnel* node. I believe increasing the geometry (for instance with *Subsurface modifier*) could potentially help.